# How to occupy the all space for image and centered focus only in media query

Tags: html, css, image

I have code here for image and I want to occupy all the remaining white space. The size of my image is 259x170 and i have a big monitor. The space will disappear only if I resize my chrome to smaller. And also, in media query I only want to focus the 3 image in the center and my code is working but there's a white space when I viewed it on my phone.

Desktop

[image]

Mobile View

[image]

```css
.photo ul{
 list-style: none;
 margin: 0 -3px 0 -40px;
 display: inline-flex;
}

.photo ul li{
 margin-right: 2px;
}

.photo ul li img{
 width: 100%;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 700px){
  .photo ul{
        margin: 0 -3px 0 -39.5%;
        width: 167%;
    }

    .photo ul li{
        margin-right: 0;
    }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 450px){
    .photo ul{
        margin-left: -42.5%;
    }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 390px){
    .photo ul{
        margin-left: -44.8%;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="photo" align="center">
  <ul>
   <li><img src="common/img/img2.png"></li>
   <li><img src="common/img/img3.png"></li>
   <li><img src="common/img/img4.png"></li>
   <li><img src="common/img/img5.png"></li>
   <li><img src="common/img/img6.png"></li>
  </ul>
 </div>
```

Comment: I cannot see any white space when i view it on mobile. check this link https://codepen.io/Xenio/pen/ywwNZP

Comment: What browser on the phone?

Comment: @Wayne i'm using Google Chrome browser

Comment: I'm using chrome browser on my Android, I'm getting centered images webhosting it from my desktop to my Andriod, via a wifi connection. I'm not able to duplicate what you are seeing. Align=center is obsolete but it is still working? It should be replaced by text-align: center; in css. But you may have a cache copy on your phone? Try turning off the phone and clearing cache. Could be that your version of chrome on the cell phone does not support the obsolete property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to me because of you parent div doesn't have width so the child div are not take with according to the need, so please provide width to the parent div and child div also, kindly consider the css suggested for the solution

Suggested css for solution

```
.photo ul{
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    list-style: none;
   display: inline-flex;
}

.photo ul li{
    margin-right: 2px;
    float: left;
    width: 20%;
}

.photo ul li img{
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Hi, It working in Desktop version. Do you know how to do it mobile ver??

Comment: Hi, Give width 100% to you li .photo ul li {width:100%} and change .photo ul { display: inline-flex;} to { display: inherit;} in media query for mobile.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried this already?

```
.photo ul{ 
list-style: none; 
margin: 0 -3px 0 -40px; 
display: flex; 
flex-wrap: wrap; 
}
```

When you use display:flex and flex-wrap:wrap you should align all the elements horizontally. You can see it more clearly on this tutorial under flex-wrap property:
https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: For the OP, and future users, to understand what you did, and why, explain your answers. Posting a code w/o is pretty useless, even if it does solve an issue.